# Stanford core NLP - Grammatical relations missing

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am trying to update a software that is using Stanford core NLP version 1.3.4 to version 3.5.1.

In the software, there are some English grammatical relations that are used. When I update the code with the new version of the library, the following English grammatical relations are missing in the new version:

1. `CONTROLLING_SUBJECT` - I think that it would be OK if I replace this with `SEMANTIC_DEPENDENT`.
2. `PURPOSE_CLAUSE_MODIFIER` - I think that this can be replaced with `ADV_CLAUSE_MODIFIER`.
3. `COMPLEMENTIZER` - this might be raplced with `MARKER` (I think).
4. `PARTICIPIAL_MODIFIER` and `INFINITIVAL_MODIFIER` could be replaced with `CLAUSAL_COMPLEMENT`.

I am not sure if this is the case, I have been digging through some documentations, but since there is a big difference between the versions 1.3.4 and 3.5.1 - I am not sure if these missing relations are now part of the relations I mentioned.

Are these replacements I've mentioned above correct? If not, with which other relations can I replace them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think any of them are *exactly* correct except for (probably) replacing CONTROLLING_SUBJECT with SEMANTIC_DEPENDENT. Most of them seem like close matches or subsets - I think even if you talked to the Standford you won't get exact replacements. I think you best bet is empirical validation. :(

Sorry, I know this isn't what you want to hear. Your guesses do seem reasonable though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (+1). I would have to wait for a more definitive answer if possible. Cheers!